# Custom syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2010 in a html file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to create syntax highlighting for custom defined words in known file type?

For example I want to have VS text editor color the tags `<@` and `@>` a specified color when viewed in a html file.

Can you do this, and if so then how is it possible?

Comment: Is that really all you want to know? The only possible answers are `Yes` or `No`. Please think a bit more about the _actual_, _answerable_ question you have and post that.

Comment: Sorry I was implying that I want to know if it is possible - then how do you do it? I should have been clearer.

Comment: That link you pointed me to states 'The SO community will not write a complete solution for you, develop a complete walk through of a problem, or do your background research for you, unless your question is specific and focused on a reasonably small scope.' - now I am not asking for a walkthrough of anything, my problem is about as small as you can get, extremely specific - and I just want someone to point me in the right direction: i.e. go to this setting in 'Tools>Options' or read this article on the msdn website possibly. I have google my problem and searched stack overflow, but all the...

Comment: ...other questions are related to writing your own syntax highlighting. Now if someone else has a similar problem to me in the future, i.e. 'Is it possible to create syntax highlighting for custom defined words in known file type' and they google it like I did, now they will find something - this question - but instead of finding something useful they will simply read someone lecturing someone for no apparent reason on 'how to post a question on stack overflow'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, well, certainly this is possible for C++ files and files that Visual Studio recognises; so if VS is set up to recognise your HTML as C++ files you should be good.

You will need to create a **usertype.dat** file and place it in your

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE
```

folder (or equivalent for VS2010, this is for VS2008)

This file should have the keywords you want listed separately on each line;

for example; I develop with Qt and I have a **usertype.dat** file as:

```
signal
slots
Q_OBJECT
```

(and so on)

Restart VS and your keywords will be highlighted.

I got the info from [here](http://www.cumps.be/nl/blog/read/visual-studio-2008-and-php-coloring) and verified it on my system.

Comment: brilliant, thought this question was well dead!

Comment: Was hunting for the same sort of thing and found this question open :)

Comment: Thanks Rob :)  Was just about to give up on this since I couldn't be bothered with the Managed Package Framework.